# Give the instance list the control to edit the list, not the items

Tags: c#, 2sxc

I typically use the control  @Edit.Toolbar(Content, actions:"edit,new,remove,instance-list") on the items themselves. Then the user can edit the entire list from click the button on any of the items. Logically, it would make more sense for them to click the instance-list button from the **ListContent**

In previous versions of 2SXC, the user could hover over the DNN black and white pencil icon and click "Edit List" which made a lot of sense. This control is not available in newer versions of 2SXC so they have to edit the list by going to any of the list items.

I tried using 'instance-list' in the ListContent controls but it doesn't seem to be available there. Is there a way to give the instance-list control to the ListContent control?

I have a scenario where this is especially important. On some lists that I have, I prefer to force my user to use the Edit List to enter a list title but also edit content from the list interface rather than me putting the  around every link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *instance-list* is the correct button, just ATM it doesn't offer the additional buttons. I believe others have requested it as well, we just haven't found time to implement it. You can open a new issue, but code-contributions would work even better :)

Comment: Any update about this topic?

We recently updated our DNN installation from 7.2 to 9.2 and, consequently, 2sxc from 6.6.5 to 9.32.
We made extensive use of this feature in the past, populating a "database" of elements and then showing elements on a page while hiding them in another page. 

Seeing this feature as gone really left us distraught.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really remember what this is about. Could you maybe post a new issue with more details?

Comment: Briefly, in old versions 2sxc provided the button "Edit list", on top of the others while editing, that permitted to edit a list of items to show (see https://imgur.com/a/HrxOnWl).

Newer versions seem to have removed this option.

Currently, we have resolved by porting sxc 6.6.5 to DNN 9.3

Comment: This still works - it's in the second set (list-buttons) https://imgur.com/a/Iqt2lmb

Comment: It seems that I can't see all that stuff from my module: the only buttons I see are these, in an animated gif: https://imgur.com/oFLnyPP

Comment: One of two things happend. Either your template doesn't have a toolbar - so you are just seeing the fallback toolbar provided to ensure you can access admin etc. OR your template isn't configured to be a list. I would suggest adding @Edit.Toolbar() anywhere in the file and probably you'll get the toolbar you want :)

Comment: No luck with @Edit.Toolbar(). And the template is a list https://imgur.com/a/5mFARhK

Comment: sorry, the empty Edit.Toolbar also just gives a default toolbar. To get the one with the list, you need to use @Edit.Toolbar(item) - where Item is an entity from the list. It can be the default `Content` object or an item inside your loop.

Comment: Now it works! Thank you very much for your support!